# How to Compile project based on Closure Library + OpenLayers 3 + Proj4js

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library, openlayers-3, proj4js

I am building an app using Closure Library, OL3 and Proj4js.
Now I want to compile project with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS in closure compiler, I don't want to load all OL3 build and all closure library scripts but only those I use.

I read something about externs and exports on closure library site, but still I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone tell me where I can find good tutorial about this or tell me how to do it?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There is no such tutorial right now. You can have a look at https://github.com/camptocamp/ngeo to see how we do it for the ngeo framework.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but still: There is now a tutorial explaining how to compile your application together with OpenLayers:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/doc/tutorials/closure.html